# CSS - Image wrong alignment and off bounds

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The WordPress website is working well for more than a year.  Perhaps, it is because of the new browser versions, the alignment is off.

[image]

As you can see, each image should be inside their respective bounding box, but they are now off bounds.

HTML code:

```html
<div class="full-container commercial">
<div class="container">
<div id="content" class="clearfix row">
<div id="main" class="col col-lg-12 clearfix" role="main">
<article id="post-12" class="clearfix post-12 page type-page status-publish hentry" role="article">
<section class="post_content">
<h2>Community</h2>
<ul id="equalize" class="gallery_block commercial">
<p></p>
<li style="height: 601px;">
<span class="wp-easy-gallery">
<a style="cursor: pointer;" title="Senior Apartment" onclick="var images=['http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/302-1.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/302-2.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/302-3.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/302-4.jpg']; var titles=['Senior Apartment', 'Senior Apartment', 'Senior Apartment', 'Senior Apartment']; var descriptions=['', '', '', '']; jQuery.prettyPhoto.open(images,titles,descriptions);">
<img class="dShadow trans" border="0" alt="Senior Apartment" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/302-1.jpg">
<p class="wpeg-gallery-name left">Senior Apartment</p>
</span>
</li>
<li style="height: 601px;">
<span class="wp-easy-gallery">
<a style="cursor: pointer;" title="Cultural Centre" onclick="var images=['http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/412-1.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/412-2.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/412-3.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/412-4.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/412-5.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/412-6.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/.../412-14.jpg']; var titles=['Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', '', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre', 'Cultural Centre']; var descriptions=['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']; jQuery.prettyPhoto.open(images,titles,descriptions);">
<img class="dShadow trans" border="0" alt="Cultural Centre" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/412-1.jpg">
<p class="wpeg-gallery-name left">Cultural Centre</p>
</span>
</li>
<li style="height: 601px;">
<span class="wp-easy-gallery">
<a style="cursor: pointer;" title="Community Centre" onclick="var images=['http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/541-1.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/541-2.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/541-3.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/541-4.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/541-5.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/541-6.jpg', 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/...Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre', 'Community Centre']; var descriptions=['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']; jQuery.prettyPhoto.open(images,titles,descriptions);">
<img class="dShadow trans" border="0" alt="Community Centre" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/541-1.jpg">
</a>
<p class="wpeg-gallery-name left">Community Centre</p>
</span>
</li>
<li style="height: 601px;">
<li style="height: 601px;">
<li style="height: 601px;">
<p class="lead"></p>
</ul>
</section>
<footer>
</article>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div
```

CSS:

```css
.wp-easy-gallery {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.wp-easy-gallery a {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.wp-easy-gallery img {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
.wp-easy-gallery:hover img.dShadow {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
}
.wp-easy-gallery:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.wp-easy-gallery img {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.wpeg-gallery-name.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.wpeg-gallery-name.right {
    text-align: right;
```

This was done by a previous programmer.  We should appreciate if anyone can let us know what possibly went wrong and where to look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this solves the image problem, but your HTML appears to have some syntax errors, particularly some misplaced or missing closing tags. You might want to check it with a tool like [DirtyMarkup](https://dirtymarkup.com/), [HTML Tidy](https://infohound.net/tidy/), [HTML Lint](http://www.htmllint.net/en/html-lint/htmllint.html), etc.

Comment: is that all the HTML in your body? Showdev is right, you have some weirdness going on here. What is the desired outcome with these images?

Comment: Provide us a LIVE DEMO Link of your HTML File.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on CSS for quite a while.  Thanks all for your help.

I have added the following to .wp-easy-gallery

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

and change

```
<li style="height: 601px;"
```

to

```
<li>
```

on Firebug and it starts to align well.

Since I am not familiar with WordPress, I guess I need to try to dig into it and see where I can change the CSS.  Since different browsers behave differently, I guess I can start from here and then test it on different browsers.